# How to modify every row in the column with procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following table:

```
-----------------
ID | DESCRIPTION
-----------------
7  | qweqwe
8  | asdasd
9  |
10 | zxczxc
```

How can I use the procedure to make her like this?

```
-----------------
ID | DESCRIPTION
-----------------
7  | qweqwe_[7]
8  | asdasd_[8]
9  |
10 | zxczxc_[10]
```

That is, if the field is not empty, then I need to add to the end `_[id]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a procedure, it can be done in SQL only.

```
update your_table
set    your_column = your_column || '_[' || your_id || ']'
where  your_column is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select id, description||'_[' || id || ']' 
from table 
where description is not null;
```

Yeh you want to update, then use `update` statement:

```
update table 
set description=description||'_[' || id || ']'  
where description is not null;
```